# Webpackのloaderを通すとファイルの内容が変わってしまう

Tags: javascript, webpack

## やりたいこと

Webpackする時に、テキストファイルをそのままstringとしてimportしたい。
（最終的にglslifyを使ってglsl文字列を扱いたい）

## 期待する結果

以下の内容でWebpackし、メインのjsを走らせた時に「aaaa」が出力される。

raw.txt

```
aaaa
```

index.js

```js
import raw from 'raw-loader!./raw.txt';

export function main(){
  console.log(raw);
}
```

期待される出力

```
aaaa
```

## 実際の結果

出力された内容は以下でした。

```
export default "aaaa";
```

（シンタックスハイライトされてしまいますが、文字列です）

ロードされるraw.txtの内容が、元の内容を文字列としてexportするjsファイルのように書き変わってしまっています。
一方で、この書き変わった内容全体が文字列として読み込まれているので、exportされた内容をimportするようなこともできません。

**raw.txtの内容をそのまま読み込むか、jsの形に書き変わった内容をjsとして読み込むかするには、どうすれば良いでしょうか？**

---

詳細な構成は以下です。

ファイル

```
root
│  node_modules
│  package.json
│  webpack.config.js
└─ src
    └─ js
        │  index.js
        └─ raw.txt
└─ dist
    │  main.js
    └─ index.html
```

webpack.config.js

```js
var path = require('path');
var test = {
  mode: 'development',
  target: ['web', 'es6'],
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src/js/index.js'),
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname,'dist'),
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
    {
      test: /\.txt$/i,
      use: 'raw-loader',
    }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
  },
};
module.exports = [
  test
];
```

macOS: 12.3
node: v16.4.1
webpack: 5.64.1
webpack-cli: 4.9.1
raw-loader:4.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。

raw-loaderはWepBack4以前のためのもので、WebPack5からはAsset Moduleを使うようです。
これらを導入したところ無事に動きました。

参考：

- [webpack 5からurl-loader/file-loader/raw-loaderが要らなくなった](https://qiita.com/Tsukina_7mochi/items/e031f12a122e05ff8d87)
- [【webpack5】静的ファイルの公開設定にAsset Modulesを使う](https://marsquai.com/745ca65e-e38b-4a8e-8d59-55421be50f7e/99181429-1958-4966-90c1-2e9357ecf450/9c23df88-0922-49c6-b4c1-20050cc1e91e/)